# new Canvas(bitmap) crashs on galaxy s but works on nexus

Tags: android, canvas, galaxy

can someone tell me why my app works fine on samsumg galaxy nexus but crashes on samsung galaxy s?
i found out that it crashes at this line:

```
bMapRpm=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.canvasback);
canvasRpm = new Canvas(bMapRpm);
```

the BitmapFactory.decodeResource works fine but when i create the new Canvas it crashes.

i can't post the logcat because my galaxy s (i don't know why) doesn't support logcat

can someone help me?

Comment: The Galaxy S supports logcat, try `adb logcat` in the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, bitmap must be mutable. Doc: "Construct a canvas with the specified bitmap to draw into. The bitmap must be mutable."

You can:

```
bMapRpm=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.canvasback);

Bitmap mutableCopy = Bitmap.createBitmap(bMapRpm.getWidth(),bMapRpm.getHeight(),bMapRpm.getConfig());
canvasRpm = new Canvas(mutableCopy);
canvasRpm.drawBitmap(bMapRpm, null, null);
bMapRpm.recycle();
```

..do whatever want with canvas

Comment: hmm and how can i make it mutable? and why does it work on nexus?

Comment: thx that was the problem. but i still don't understand how it could work on nexus but not on glaxy s

Comment: different implementation approaches. The documentation doesn't say if bitmap given by decodeResource should be mutable.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to create mutable bitmap, 
use Bitmap.copy(confit, is_mutable), 
you can try it:

```
bMapRpm=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.canvasback);
Bitmap mutableCopy = bMapRpm.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
canvasRpm = new Canvas(mutableCopy);
```